# Netbeans scanning of project too slow

Tags: netbeans, ide

I use netbeans 7.3.1,  i have found here one way how to make netbeans faster: [How to improve Netbeans performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229763/how-to-improve-netbeans-performance), but my problem is that my netbeans is to slow by project scanning, is projectcanning important for the software **netbeans**? My projects are in network and not on my pc. I have also found this plugin, but there is no more available: http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand

My CPU is Intel quad 2.40GHz.

Comment: Close unnecessary projects. You can easily open them as soon as you need them. Check var/log/messages to see if there is any issue. Seems to me that the network is slow.

Comment: Thanke you Costis Aivalis, i work always only on 1 project, and always is to slow,but after your message i thing this is network problem.

Comment: try cleaning all the cache first, it worked for me twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans

Answer (score 14):

Try to disable auto-scanning of sources. Make sure that you only modify the sources via Netbeans. According to the manual:

**Enable auto-scanning of sources**
When selected, the IDE will scan the source code of projects to detect any files that were modified externally. Scanning is triggered when the focus is returned to the IDE, for example when the user returns to the IDE from another application.
If your sources are only modified from within the IDE, you can probably disable auto-scanning with little risk of encountering problems. Disabling auto-scanning may improve IDE performance if you are working on large projects.
Auto-scanning is enabled by default.

[image]

Other than that it the network that causes the delay.

Comment: In my netbeans is this option "disabled", i have tried with both variants

Comment: Can I at least disable this feature from running at startup? I have some very large projects in my workspace and it takes a very long time to complete

Comment: I don't know if i understand your question well, but once you check auto-scanning out NB will never do auto-scanning unless you check it in again.

Comment: 10 mins of loading => 0.2secs . Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer didn't work for me. But if your OS is Windows, I only found one way to significantly decrease the amount of time it takes to open my remote project and hopefully it will work for you.

1. Open Programs and Features.
2. Select Turn Windows features on or off.
3. Uncheck Remote Differential Compression.

[image: Windows Features]

Beyond disabling that, depending on the size of your project, netbeans indexes your project during each launch in order to track changes that have been made. Application modules are also cached which causes a further delay as well.

One more thing you can try which may help if your project or netbeans version has significantly changed, and was recommended in the comments above, is to clear the cache.

You can either rename the folder, or delete it (netbeans will recreate it).

Paths: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Answer (score 0):

Scanning performance of Netbeans can be improved using the following procedure :
1) Go to Window-->Files. This opens the Files Tab.
2) In the Files Tab for each opened project open the nbproject folder and inside it open the project.properties file.
3) Now in this file below the property "excludes" there are file references listed for all your referred Libraries (JARs)
4) There might be some repeated file references with incorrect paths on your network.
5) Delete those old incorrect path references.
Example -
`excludes=`
`file.reference.xyz.jar=../not/correct/path.jar  //delete this line`
`file.reference.xyz.jar-1=../correct/path.jar    //remove -1`
`....`
`includes=**`

6)Also locate the property "javac.classpath" and delete the unnecessary classpath entries corresponding to the deleted references as described above.
Example -
`javac.classpath=\`
`${file.reference.xyz.jar}:\       //delete this line`
`${file.reference.xyz.jar-1}:\     //remove -1`
`....`
`javac.compilerargs=`

7) So now the file reference mentioned in the file reference section and the javac.classpath property is same and points to a valid Library (JAR) address on your machine or network.
Example -
`excludes=`
`file.reference.xyz.jar=../correct/path.jar   //the correct reference & path`
`....`
`includes=**`
`....`
`javac.classpath=\`
`${file.reference.xyz.jar}:\       //the correct classpath entry for reference`
`....`
`javac.compilerargs=`
`....`

The reason the above procedure worked (in my case) is because it prevents Netbeans from scanning unnecessary Library paths that may not be present on your machine/network.