# Netbeans 8.0 and networks project are too slow

Tags: java, php, netbeans, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a VMware Virtual Machine running on my PC because I use it as a development environment. I'm running on the VM CentOS 6.5. I have a Samba shared folder on that VM and I connect through "host-only" connection from Windows 7 to CentOS without any problem.

Now I create a project using a shared folder as project sources and opening Netbeans and wait for the project to be opened takes sometimes 15 min or more.

I disable "background scanning" following instructions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003822/background-scanning-of-projects-slows-down-netbeans-7-2) but still to slow, any advice on this one? What is the best approach? Use remote project sources through SFTP connection?

Answer (score 0):

The real fix would be a fix of your samba. There is very likely some locking due to some network timeout in it. Most likely it is some WINS/DNS configuration problem. Only you can debug it (tcpdump/strace the samba process).

However, the best approach is not the fix of your samba, but using a different version for deployment. Your question makes likely that you have your development environment on your Windows host machine, and you deploy your code to your CentOS.

Use a native filesystem on your host, typically bound it into a versioning system (most likely, git), and make the deployment a part of your build scripts. For example, you could install a [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and then upload your compiled code (or even the source) to your VM by an [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). This rsync can already be called from your build script (like maven-exec-plugin in a pom.xml, if you use maven).