# when java jvm compiles bytecode, where does that code go in process space?

Tags: java, memory, process, jvm, jvm-hotspot

When the jvm (hotspot in my case) permanently compiles certain code paths into machine code, where is that machine code being stored? in the .text segment of process memory? in the process's heap??

<s>I am not talking about JITing. From my understandning, JIT will compile and run bytecode without ever saving the compiled code anywhere. But what about when the jvm *is* saving that code -- where in process space does it save it?</s>
 ... as the comments and answers point out, everything I was asking for is, in fact, a part of JIT.

EDIT:

as per my comment below, the situation I'm specifically referring to is documented here as "Adaptive optimization": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#hotspot

Comment: When does the JVM produce compiled code other than during JITing?

Comment: The JVM does not permanently compile to bytecode to native machine code. Thus it is not persistently stored anywhere.

Comment: @AlexanderBird: That _is_ JITting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, what you are describing is JIT - specifically how it works in Hotspot

To answer your question about where the code is saved *at runtime* - it's in the process heap and the pointers to the method code in the object's Klass file is updated to point to it.  There's also something called OSR (on stack replacement) for compiling long running loops directly on the stack.

Comment: Thank you for both answering my question and deciphering what I was trying to ask :)

Comment: Is the compiled code stored in the same "code cache" that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513185/what-is-reservedcodecachesize) talks about? If so, if I increase -Xmx, will that affect the code cache?

Comment: Yes it is and I think it would be best to use the explicit option mentioned in this post i.e. `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize`

Comment: That's not quite true: the process heap is usually protected by OS from being executable.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't worked with production-quality VMs, but here are my five cents.

`.text` sections in Unix executables belong to the *file* which stores executable code; at run-time this file section is mapped to a memory area allocated by the system linker during program initialization, that's all (on Linux, you can see the sections layout in memory in `/proc/$PID/maps`).

As for JIT-compilation on Unix-like systems, I can only think of memory areas which have been allocated by [`mmap` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with `PROT_EXEC` flag enabled. This call is specified by POSIX standards and used by the Linux's system linker, `ld.so`, to load any native executable file into memory. This call can be equally used for allocating new executable memory areas at run-time.

The usual heap is often protected by OS/[MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) from being executed, as any `/proc/$PID/maps` file suggests:

```
00dd4000-01292000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [heap]
```

here `rw-p` means that no data in `[heap]` can be executed (though, e.g., it is not the case with 32-bit x86 CPUs without PAE, they don't have hardware capability to prevent running some memory data as code), but can be read/written.

So a VM needs a dedicated memory area with code execution permission. Indeed, let's look for `rwx` memory areas in some java process memory layout:

```
# cat /proc/12929/maps | grep rwx        # I run a Java VM with PID 12929
f3700000-f3940000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0  # - an unnamed executable & writable region
```

Then execution of native code is a matter of assembling JIT-compiled native code either position-independently (like shared objects code is compiled, with `gcc` option `-fPIC`) or using the address returned by `mmap()`.