# How to remove obsolete java classfiles?

Tags: java

Every time I need to delete the previous files to force the compiler not cache

I compile it using:

```
javac Main.java
```

and other imported files are nor compiled, until deleted

Comment: What's being cached that you don't want to be cached? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you want to increment the cachesize instead like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513185/what-is-reservedcodecachesize

Comment: javac Main.java will never try to compile imported classes

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht are you sure javac and JIT compiler share the same parameters?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht: javac and the JVM's JIT definitely do not share the same parameters.

Comment: k, thanks on that. Pity I can't edit my comment. Deleting it doesn't seem an option.

Comment: I mean, I want to fully disable cache, thus every time i write javac, Main.java and other imported files were fully recompiled, as if I were compiling it at the first time, thats what I want is that possible?

Comment: *What* 'compile caching'? What makes you think there even is such a thing? There isn't. If you want to ensure a class is compiled, just delete the .class file first. You can't describe the entire file system as a 'compile cache'.

Comment: It should update those implicitly compiled class files when their source files change, so the cache is not a big problem. It only means that *deleted* classes will persist, which you can clean up when you're ready to build a jar.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you don't want ALL imported classes to be deleted (`java.lang`?) but only your project. Simple: Delete all `.class` files in your output folder, recursively, with your shell's tools. If you have a dedicated output folder you can just delete the whole folder.

Best method: Learn a build tool like Maven or Ant and use the integrated ways to clean a project output, e.g. with Maven `mvn clean`. Or if you use an IDE with a built-in builder (e.g. Eclipse) there might be a clean option for the project.

This is not a "cache" in a strict sense.