# How can I reduce vert.x memory consuption

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm-arguments, vert.x

I read this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/VuKsUzUah88

and I don't know how to access the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` in the current vertx version.

I tried following command:

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.0-snapshot-fat.jar -conf config.json -Xms128m -Xmx400m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=48m
```

and doesn't seem to hava any effect to my apps mem consumption.
do you have any advice for me?

thanks in advance

kdeux

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.0-snapshot-fat.jar -conf config.json -DDEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx400m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=48m"
```

Comment: yes I have tried this, but this didn't solve my problem

Comment: Read about Java 8 ReservedCodeCacheSize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513185/what-are-reservedcodecachesize-and-initialcodecachesize