# Java out of memory

Tags: java, memory

I have a class named CacheDownloader for my client that downloads an unzips updates for my  main jar, the client. I had a problem with that because it couldn't unzip the new client and replace it while in use, so I had to make a new jar (named ClientUpdater) that would unzip the new client to replace the old, then open the new one.

ClientUpdater opens the client back up no problem. However the CacheDownloader cannot open ClientUpdater, it gets an out of memory error.

CacheDownloader still downloads all the new files and unzips the brunt of the files, all ClientUpdater does is unzip a tiny zip file that contains a fairly small client.

Here is how CacheDownloader loads ClientUpdater:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + getCacheDir() + "/ClientUpdater.jar");
System.exit(0);
```

Here is the full error message - http://gyazo.com/8105ffd4c35f5f6d4a68a770fedf8f92

Hopefully that is enough context and information without it being to lengthy. My question now is, how can I go about fixing this? The error says I can increase the reserved code cache, is there a negative side to this? And how do I do that anyway, Google didn't really show how just explained what it did.

I'm pretty new to Java so something to keep in mind.

Comment: What does your [profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) tell you, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6310284/230513)?

Comment: I dont have one, kind of new at this. The error does say the max/used/avail though, if thats what you need?

Comment: You may already have jvisualvm, which is typically included with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below steps to fix this.

1. Increase min/max heap size for your process

   `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar " + getCacheDir() + "/ClientUpdater.jar");`
2. Increase size of `ReservedCodeCacheSize` e.g. -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513185/what-are-reservedcodecachesize-and-initialcodecachesize)

You should use a profiler like [visualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/) and can find out more detail about your run time environment. e.g. memory, cpu, threads, heap size etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is RSPS. I recommend you use reflection to load the client as using *Runtime.exec* will not work on systems where the environmental variables aren't configured correctly.